# How inheritance works indeed?

Tags: java, inheritance

Please help me to understand how inheritance works.

If I have two classes, parent and child. When I create an instance of child is parent class instance constructed as well or not?

My code of `Parent` class.

```
public class Parent {
    private char s;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

And `Child`

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    private int i;

    public Child(int i) {
        super();
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

And finally the test

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child(100);
        System.out.println(child.hashCode());
        System.out.println(child.getClass().getSuperclass().hashCode());
    }
}
```

In output I get

```
100
2000502626
```

So the hashes of objects are different. It means that when I create instance of `Child` it is also created instance of `Parent`. Am I right?

Comment: A child _is a_ parent. It **is the same instance**. This is how inheritance works - they're the same object.

Comment: The second `hashCode()` call does not call the method of `Parent` but the method of the `Class` object that represents the class of a `Parent` object.

Comment: @Boris the Spider In this case how is it possible to get access to parent methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Child object a Parent constructor is invoked as well, because a Child **is a** Parent.

But when you do this:

```
System.out.println(child.getClass().getSuperclass().hashCode());
```

**you're not invoking `Parents` instance hashode**. **You are invoking hashCode() of the instance of the `Class` object**.
See what `child.getClass().getSuperclass()` returns. It returns an instance of type `Class` not of type Parent/Child.
You cannot invoke `Parents` instance methods using child.getClass().getSuperClass() - **that doesn't return the instance of a type, but an object representing this type.**

Try doing this in child method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("In child hashCode: " + i);
    System.out.println("Parents hashCode: " + super.hashCode());
    return i;
}
```

This will return 100 and 0, as `Parents` `s` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: child.getClass().getSuperclass().hashCode() represents the hashcode of which class?

Comment: java.lang.Class.class I believe.

Comment: @MichałSchielmann I think it will get the hashcode of `Parent.class` (which class is `java.lang.Class`)

Comment: @WilQu - see what child.getClass().getSuperclass() returns. It returns an instance of `Class.class`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html
This class inherits the `hashCode()` method from `Object.class`, and in `Object.class` this method is (in openjdk) `native`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java. For native methods see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557358/native-methods-in-java

Comment: @MichałSchielmann Where do you see that `getSuperclass()` returns `Class.class` ? It returns the `Class` object representing the superclass of `Child`, which is `Parent.class`.

Comment: @WilQu Please refer to the docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html
Method signature:
`public Class<? super T> getSuperclass()`. And here `Class` is `java.lang.Class.class`
So in the question `getSuperclass()` will return `Class<Parent>` and that is still an instance of type `Class` and not of type `Parent`.

Comment: PS - see @Kent answer. It states the same.

Comment: @MichałSchielmann `Parent.class` is not an instance of type `Parent`, but of type `Class<Parent>`. And `java.lang.Class.class` is not an instance of type `Class<Parent>` but an instance of type `Class<Class>`.

Comment: Where did i write that `Parent.class` or `Class.class` is an instance? I'll write this one last time:
`getSuperclass()` will return object of type `Class<? extends Parent>` and that is an instance of type `Class`, not `Parent`.

Answer (score 10):

Your question has nothing to do with inheritance.

the `100` you get from `child` instance's `hashcode()` method, as you expected.

The `2000502626` was from `Parent.class`, not `Parent object`.

`Parent.class` has type `java.lang.Class`

`parent object` has type `Parent`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there will be just one child object created. Since every child is a parent, the parent constructor will be invoked. if you print `this` in both child as well as parent instance methods, it will print the same (child object)
check - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834598/confusion-in-inheritance-value-of-this-when-printed-in-constructor)

Comment: Are you sure that there are two objects being created and not one?

Comment: @MichałSchielmann - well, actually what I meant was - *Both parent as well as child object* are created. yes, there will be encapsulated in the child object itself.So, I meantioned - *So, there will be one big (sub-class) object (this) representing/containing both the objects.*. Maybe I should have been more precise.

Comment: Still - both means two. Are there two objects or one?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have two classes, parent and child, When I create an instance of child is parent class instance constructed as well or not?

Yes. It works through Constructor. When you call constructor of your child class to create object, it first calls its parent class contructor and hence creates object of parent class

Comment: It calls its parent class constructor to initialize itself but only one object is created.

Comment: But if I call in some of my child class methods super.hashCode() I get different hash than my object has.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Both parent and child object are created. The child class constructor calls the parent(super) class constructor first, then only other functions of the child class are performed. As you can see from your own code two different values getting printed.

Comment: Are you sure there are two objects being created? What does it mean and how is it relevant: "then only other functions of the child class are performed."? The question was why are they different, and your reply does not answer that correctly.